# How to run a CGI Ruby script inside Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cgi

I'm trying to run a ruby cgi.rb script exactly like this one: http://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/?ShowTutorialCode=true from a Ruby on Rails app in order to obtain a result exactly like this one: http://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/ but inside a Rails Web app.

How can I do it please?

Comment: i would go with rack instead of cgi

Comment: Me too, but it's a legacy requirement.

Comment: Note that CGI scripts [are considered as quiet insecure and not recommended for usage](http://www.w3.org/Security/faq/wwwsf4.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but something like this should be a proper solution (not tested):

```
match '/that.cgi' => proc { |app| Rack::Handler::CGI.run app }
```

As Rails uses Rack, it supports mounting it's applications at the router. I'm not sure however about the usage of the `Rack::Handler::CGI`, it's very poorly documented.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. It let me download the cgi.rb file instead of running it. Maybe I should put it in a bin directory instead of the public one, but then can you tell me how can I tell Rack where is the file to run for the matching route?

Comment: I'm sorry, I honestly don't know any example of using cgi's with rails. There's no documentation for `Rack::Handler::CGI` (only methods, etc.) and there's rails guides on routing, that describes `lambda { |env| [200, "Content-Type: text", "test"] }`, only this ;(

Comment: Thank you anyway! I'm presently looking for an alternative.